# Self-invoking function jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, self-invoking-function

I noticed that in some places, jQuery code is wrapped in a self-invoking function like below. Why is this done, in what cases is this useful and in what cases is an unnecessary boilerplate?

```
function( $ ) {
  ...
}( jQuery );
```

Comment: you don't need the `$` global variable to represent `jQuery`, there's plenty of duplicates and resources around this.

Comment: Functions create variable scope. Your function now has a scoped `$`. That's it.

Comment: ...but this is unnecessary if your code is put in a `.ready()` handler, since you can just do `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {...});` or the shorter `jQuery(function($) {...});`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The short answer**: To prevent variable name conflicts. It is not always needed, but good practice in order to create conflict free reusable code.

**The long answer**: In javascript the $ symbol is just another variable. jQuery uses it because it is a nice shorthand instead of having to type out jQuery each time, but so can any other code (including other libraries).

To prevent conflict with other uses of a variable at the same scope (in this case $ at the "global" scope) it is common for code to be wrapped in a self-invoking function with the "conflict-free" variables passed as the function parameters. This then creates a new scope where your variable won't interfere with other uses of that variable. That way you can pass the full named variable & uses it with whatever name you want within the anonymous function.

So, when creating conflict free reusable code it is good practice to use this methodology:

```
(function( $ ) {
  ...
})( jQuery );
```

Along these lines you will also see the following format:

```
(function( $, window, undefined ) {
  ...
})( jQuery, window );
```

In this instance `undefined` is simply used for readability to indicating that no more arguments are passed to the function.

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to avoid conflict regarding use of `$`

```
function( $ ) {
  ...
}( jQuery );
```

Inside this function you can use `$` without having to worry about it's use outside of it as inside that function, `$` always refers to the `jQuery` object.

This is helpful while creating jQuery plugins,You will see jQuery plugin's use this kind of function to avoid conflicts with other plugins.

Reference `:` http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Answer (score 0):

In function scope `$` is local variable that not conflict with any other global `$`.